# How to use prism/unity for vspackage development since Bootstrapper is obsolete?

Tags: c#, wpf, unity-container, prism, vspackage

I create wpf application with Prism modularity. Now i'd like to create Visual Studio plugin(vspackage) while reusing UI part from previous app, aka using appropriate module from this app. I thought i could use Unity.Bootstrapper for it, but it seems to be obsolete and i guess deprecated in the future. 
What the way to load modules and use all Prism DI abilities in such case, when i don't have an app shell actually.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is a great question!!! I'm still actively looking for solutions to this scenario myself.

The ONLY article that I've managed to find so far that addresses this is [Dependency Injection For Visual Studio Extensions](https://dotnetfalcon.com/dependency-injection-for-visual-studio-extensions/).

Although the article uses Autofac, I imagine would that the same principles contained in it would work for other IOC containers as well. It seems to work well enough in one of his extensions at least: [Gist Manager](https://github.com/conwid/GistManager), but I've yet to successfully retrofit the technique into my own extensions (yet).

Answer (score 0):

I already have read this answer, but it doe not help me, since my application starts not as usual WPF app, but as VSPackage and its entry point is AsyncPackage, a can't to call new App(), it throw exception "can not create a new application within existing app.domain".